# Forma de organizar dados

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados

Boas.

Tenho uma questão, não tanto sobre o código com de organização de dados.

Tenho uma pequena aplicação de backup automático e a ideia era ter "um programador de tarefas", onde eu indicava as horas, o tipo de base dados (MySQL, SQL Server) e a própria connection string. O problema agora é a parte do acesso a estas configurações. Enquanto eu podia fazer querys a BD de segundo a segundo para ver se tenho algum backup a fazer, eu não quero fazer-lo já que, na minha opinião é muita carga "inútil" na BD. Então a opção é criar algo do género de um array, lista, dicionario. Uma cache. Onde iria guardar tudo que precisava.

Talvez por falta de experiência, tudo que me vem a cabeça é dicionários com listas e dicionarios ou srtings com a informação de minuto a minuto vão ser analisados a procura da informação, ou seja, tudo ao calha.

Eis alguns exemplos:

```
[hora][tipo][connectionString]
[14:00:00][MySQL][server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=12345;database=test]
[14:15:00][SQLSERVER][Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;]
```

Espero ter passado a ideia.

Qual é então uma boa "forma" de guardar estes dados?

Answer (score 1):

Entendo que você teria um JOB que rodaria de x em x tempo para verificar se esta no momento de rodar uma tarefa. Qual seria este intervalo? 
Caso seja maior que 1 minuto, sem pensar muito, já te digo que a melhor forma seria fazer um select no banco de dados. 
De qualquer forma, o banco de dados já é otimizado para isso, inclusive criando caches e controles internos. Não vejo como um problema executar esta consulta ao banco de dados.

Entendo que você pode ter mais algum limitante para querer usar esta estratégia, como servidor de aplicação e servidor de banco de dados em redes diferentes, servidores de banco de dados já sobrecarregados, e afins. Mas minha opinião é que a maneira mais otimizada para armazenar informação de constante acesso é um banco de dados. Qualquer solução de arquivo de config, xml, texto estruturado, te trará mais desenvolvimento e risco à aplicação, além da dificuldade de manutenção destas configurações.